# Object Tag and Frameset Tag doesn't work FullScreen API

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-fullscreen

I have a page inside the object tag which use Fullscreen API to make that page full screen. Unfortunately it doesn't work in object tag (except firefox )but work well in iframe tag with attribute allowFullScreen.

Here is the implementation.

[image]

**I already try other library like screenfull.js. I have to use object tag and frameset only ( that's why iframe cannot use here ). Please give me any suggestion.**

Comment: if you've find any solution of this issue somewhere or yourself, please share it.

Comment: Hi Goddard, did you find any solution to your problem?